# Array.find() or Array.some() but return a custom value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

What I can do:

```
const val = array.find((val) => <condition>);
const index = array.indexOf(val);
```

What I'd like to do:

```
const { val, index } = array.someFunc((val, index) => <condition> && { val, index });
```

Anything like this out there? `some()` is reduced to a boolean, and `find()` just returns the array element, but neither fit the use case.

Comment: `map` *then* `find`?

Comment: There is no built in function, you will have to wrap your first example in a custom function.

Comment: There's `Array.findIndex()` that would reduce some effort

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in for this. But [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) could be used:

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

const [ index, val ] = Object.entries(array).find(([i, v]) => v === 'baz');

console.log(index, val);
```

Comment: Pretty similar to @jonrsharpe's map suggestion. I'm sure there are many ways to skin this cat but I was mainly just wondering if a single function similar to what I described existed. Seems not. Wonder if it'd be anything worth adding to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in prototype to do that for an array, so you will need to create a wrapper function.

```js
let numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

function myFunction(array, find) {
  const val = array.find((val) => find == val);
  const index = array.indexOf(val);
  return { val, index };
}

console.log(myFunction(numbers, 30));
```

Most people's least favorite option is to extend `Array.prototype`, so you can call the function `array.myFunction(40)`

```js
let numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

Array.prototype.myFunction = function(find) {
  const val = this.find((v) => find == v);
  const index = this.indexOf(val);
  return { val, index };
}

console.log(numbers.myFunction(30));
```